# how to change fragment's class dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Hi I have a linearLayout containing two fragments and I add tabs with code to this layout. What I want is when I click tab1 it is ok to fragment fill itself from indicated class, but in tab2 I want to change this class to another class. Thank you

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frags">

   <fragment class="com.tugce.MitsActionBar.DoktorlarFragment"
            android:id="@+id/frag_title"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/titles_size"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" /> 

    <fragment class="com.tugce.MitsActionBar.ContentFragment"
            android:id="@+id/frag_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Change `<fragment/>` in xml layout to `<FrameLayout/>`

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frag_title"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/titles_size"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" /> 

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frag_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and add fragments programmatically:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_content, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

But at first read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer I simply replace frameLayout with my fragment = DoktorlarFragment() no errors and nothing on screen do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

Shortest version of calling a fragment

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.splash_container, new ExampleFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

`addToBackStack(null)` is optional if you want to save the fragment on stack or not..