# Replace fragment in actionbarsherlock tabs

Tags: android, android-viewpager, actionbarsherlock, fragment

I want to replace a SherlockListFragment with other SherlockListFragment but I don´t know how to accomplish this

I use this code to create the fragment tabs:

```
public class MyTabsViewPager extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
....

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
            mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);           

            setContentView(mViewPager);
            bar = getSupportActionBar();
            bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            bar.setTitle("TAB");

            mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);

            mTabsAdapter.addTab(
                    bar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.icon),  
                    Fragment1.class, null);

            mTabsAdapter.addTab(
                    bar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.icon2),     
                    FragmentList.class, null);

        }
}
```

What i need is to replace in the same tab the FragmentList.class with other fragment Class

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well actually you can just replace the name of the class there. Is that what you are trying achieve?

Comment: I want to replace it dinamically when I press a button

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is too late but you can replace fragments dynamically. There's only one catch, you cannot add a fragment to the layout statically in this case. For more details - refer the solution to [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431516/how-to-change-fragments-class-dynamically)